# Debian - Ejecutar mongodb al arrancar

Tags: mongodb, debian, mongod, debian-9

Tengo un problema con Debian 9, no encuentro forma (Googleando) de hacer que **mongodb** se ejecute apenas cargue el sistema operativo.

Tengo instalado Debian 9 sin entorno gráfico.
He probado:

```
systemctl enable mongod.service
```

Y no pasa *absolutamente nada*, no funciona.
Cómo puedo entonces hacer que **mongodb** se ejecute apenas el sistema esté cargado?

> Nota: **`mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --port 27017`** corre perfectamente y es justo esa linea de *"codigo"* lo que quiero que se ejecute apenas arranque el sistema.

Comment: Hola Máxima. ¿Ves algún error en el log? Ejecuta `journalctl -u mongod.service` para que veas el log del servicio de MongoDB.

Comment: *--No entries--*

Comment: @Guz ese es el mensaje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la respuesta, después de tanto revolcar información y haciendo pruebas.

### Para instalar mongodb como servicio:

Hay que ser **root** *sí o sí*

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-server
```

### Para iniciar el servicio de MongoDB

```
#Debes ser root
service mongodb start
```

### Para configurar mongodb

```
nano /etc/mongodb.conf
```

### Reiniciar el servicio mongodb

```
#Debes ser root
service mongodb restart

#Tambíen podrías:
service mongodb stop
service mongodb start
```